# Reduce repetition in similar queries

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send where statements to a method which are dynamically executed in a LINQ statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782079/how-can-i-send-where-statements-to-a-method-which-are-dynamically-executed-in-a)

I have been writing simple LINQ queries in separate methods, but they have become repetitive. Please excuse the silly example of name and place, the only part that changes in all three methods is the 'where' clause.

How can this repetitive code be made more [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

For example, something like a helper method that takes everything the same but allows change in where clause.

```
public IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeData(int num1, int num2)
{
  var temp = from Name in Names
             from Place in Places
             where Name.id == num1 && Place.id = num2
             select new NamePlace {
                  field1 = Name.name;
                  field2 = Place.name;
             };
  return temp;
}

public IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeData2(int num1, int num2)
{
  var temp = from Name in Names
             from Place in Places
             where Name.age == num1 && Place.streetNumber = num2
             select new NamePlace {
                  field1 = Name.name;
                  field2 = Place.name;
             };
  return temp;
}

public IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeData3(int num1, int num2)
{
  var temp = from Name in Names
             from Place in Places
             where Name.favouriteNumber == num1 && Place.neighbourNumber = num2
             select new NamePlace {
                  field1 = Name.name;
                  field2 = Place.name;
             };
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: why not use or statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a parameter of type `Func<T1, T2, bool>` where `T1` and `T2` are the types of the items in `Names` and `Places` respectively.

```
private IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeDataHelper(Func<Name, Place, bool> filter)
{
  var query = from name in Names
             from place in Places
             where filter(name, place)
             select new NamePlace {
                  field1 = name.name,
                  field2 = place.name,
             };
  return query;
}

public IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeData1(int num1, int num2)
{
    return GetSomeDataHelper((name, place) => name.id == num1 && place.id = num2);
}
```

Comment: Was just about to post virtually identical code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `Func<Name, Place,bool>` to the method, evaluate it in the Where clause.

```
public IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeData(Func<Name,Place, bool> condition)
{
  var temp = from Name in Names
             from Place in Places
             where condition(Name,Place)
             select new NamePlace {
                  field1 = Name.name;
                  field2 = Place.name;
             };
  return temp;
}
```

Then invoke the function like this:

```
GetSomeData((name,place)=>name.FavNumber=5 && Place.Neighbor==7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so GetSomeData() accepts a predicate:

```
public IEnumerable<NamePlace> GetSomeData(int num1, int num2, Func<Name, Place, bool> predicate)
{
    var temp = from Name in Names
         from Place in Places
         where predicate(Name, Place)
         select new NamePlace {
              field1 = Name.name;
              field2 = Place.name;
         };
   return temp;
}
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
var results = GetSomeData(num1, num2, (name, place) => name.id == num1 && place.id = num2);
```